# How to prevent the input received in one Activity via a bluetooth input device from propagating to other activities started after this one finishes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bluetooth

I have an application in which I scan for input using a bluetooth scanner. When my current intent receives an input, I setResult and finish the activity, and then another intent is started. However, when my activity receives input and closes and after that when a new activity is started, instead of allowing me to scan a new input, it takes the old input and moves on. How do I stop this. This is what I am doing inside onCreate():

```
  barcodeEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.barcode_input);
  barcodeEntry.requestFocus();
  barcodeEntry.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Received Scan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra(WorkflowUtil.EXTRA_ACTION, barcodeEntry.getText().toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
  }
});
```

This is what my EditText decalaration in layout look like:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/barcode_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

How do I stop this. Will it work if I stop a View from receving focus when it is loaded?

Comment: can you please explain what you need? that the soft keyboard will be hidden? that the view will have its focus removed? that the soft keyboard will be shown?

Comment: I want the view to not have focus when the activity starts, but to be focused when input is received via a bluetooth input device.

Comment: Also having trouble following with the description given above.

Comment: ok, not quite sure why you need it, but i've provided now some functions that might be useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's how to hide the softkeyboard of the view:

```
/** hides the soft keyboard for a specific view */
public static void hideSoftKeyboardFromFocusedView(final Context context, final View view) 
  {
  final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
  }
```

a similar thing can be done to show the softkeyboard.

here's how to force focus on a EditText, and by this, also show the softkeyboard, even if the view already has focus:

```
public static void forceFocusOnView(final View view) 
  {
  view.post(new Runnable() 
    {
    @Override
    public void run() 
      {
      view.clearFocus();
      view.post(new Runnable() 
        {
        @Override
        public void run() 
          {
          view.requestFocus();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

if that doesn't work, you can use:

```
public static void focusAndShowSoftKeyboardOnView(final View v) 
  {
  new Handler().post(new Runnable() 
    {
    @Override
    public void run() 
      {
      v.requestFocus();
      }
    });
  final InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  if (m != null)
    m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
  }
```